# How to validate if one field contains some value according to another field jquery rules messages

Tags: jquery, asp.net, if-statement, conditional-statements

So I have two radio buttons, one is 'Yes' and the other is 'No', and I have a textbox. All of  them are asp.net controls. I'm trying to require a value in the textbox if the 'Yes' Radio button is checked, and not require it if the 'No' Radio button is checked. I need to do this using jQuery rules and messages. Does anyone know how to do this for the following controls?

```
<asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rbYes" GroupName="radioGroup" Text="Yes"/>
<asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rbNo" GroupName="radioGroup" Text="No"/>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtBox"/>
```

Comment: We need just a little more information. If you could post what jQuery you have so far, you are more likely to get the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot,

This is how I solved my question:

1. To disable or enable the text box, I put the following piece of code in `$(document).ready()` portion in jQuery script block:

   ```
   if($('#<%= rbNo.ClientID  %>').is(':checked')) {
       txtBox.attr('disabled', true);
   } else {
       txtBox.removeAttr('disabled');
   }
   ```
2. To add rules to jQuery validate (also in `$(document).ready()` code block):

   ```
   var rules = {
       txtBox: {
           required: true,
           messages: {required: "Required field when Yes is checked"}
       }
   };

   $('#<%= rbNo.ClientID  %>').click(function (e) {
       if (this.checked) {
           txtBox.attr('disabled', true);
           addOrRemoveRules(rules, "remove");
       }
       else {
           txtBox.removeAttr('disabled');
           addOrRemoveRules(rules, "add");
       }
   });
   ```
3. Now outside the `$(document).ready()` code block, and in the `javascript` code block, you'll need to include the function needed to add or remove rules and messages:

   ```
   function addOrRemoveRules(rulesObj, operation){
   if (operation == "add") {
           for (var item in rulesObj){
               $('#'+item).rules('add',rulesObj[item]);  
           }
       }
       else{
           for (var item in rulesObj){
              $('#'+item).rules('remove');
           }
       }           
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `ClientID` property of .NET controls. For instance, to determine if the "yes" radio button is checked, use

```
var yesIsChecked = $('#<%=rbYes.ClientID%>').is(':checked');
```

Likewise, to test if the textbox is empty, use

```
var txtBoxIsEmpty = $('#<%=txtBox.ClientID%>').val() == "";
```

You can use this in combination with e.g. a custom validator to accomplish your objective. More info on custom validators [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020145934/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/073102-1.aspx). Towards the bottom, the article mentions the `ClientValidationFunction` property, which should contain the name of a function that performs the validation logic. The MSDN reference is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx)